# How do you select the selector with jquery on function?

Tags: jquery

For example I have this event

```
$('body').on('click','.class', function() {
    //something
});
```

how do i get the element with the .class class that i clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` to get javascript object or `$(this)` to get jquery object.

```
$('body').on('click','.class', function() {
   alert(this.id);  //with this, javascript provided properties or methods.
   alert($(this).attr('id')); // with $(this) jquery provided properties or methods.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You still access it by `$(this)`, just as you would in a `.click`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EEMjt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with `$(this)` inside the handler

```
$('body').on('click','.class', function() {
    $(this)  or this  // This points to the element with .class
             // which you just clicked
    alert($(this).attr('class') ); // Gets the class name
});
```

Comment: the $(this) will choose the body tag, not the element with the .class tag.

Comment: nope .. It will select the .class as it has been delegated to the body

Comment: $('body').on('click', function() {  will select the body  , but $('body').on('click','.class', function() { will select the .class which is nested inside the body

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.class', function() {
    $(this).<some property here>;
 });
```